# Width issue for class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my function. I've tried everything I know but nothing. Closest output [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mn763x4q/8/)

When I have a starting paragraph element with class `num`, my code has an output but anyway, the code should stop executing when reaching end of 1st line, but still goes further by 2 paragraphs.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() { num() }, 10);
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("num");
var myP = setInterval(function() { pelem() }, 50)
// Generates random number on random element with class num
function num() {
  var i = z.length;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
  z[y].innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
}

// generates paragraph with class num
function pelem() {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.classList.add("num");
  var element = document.getElementById("example");
  var x = document.getElementById("example");
  var one = x.offsetWidth;
  var i = z.length;
  var p = z[0].clientWidth;
  var y = one / p;
  var two = i * y;
  if (i > y) {
    clearInterval(myP);
  } else {
    element.appendChild(para);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}

#example {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.lol {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="example">
    <p class="num"> </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

But when I delete main paragraph my function have no output. Example on [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mn763x4q/11/)
Please give me some advice.

What I would like to achieve: 
The number of paragraphs should be not more than can be putted in 1 line block.

Comment: Have you checked the error console when running without the initial `p`? If not do so - you will see a problem. The line `var z = document.getElementsByClassName("num");` , what do you expect `z` to be if there is no paragraph?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/qohLp6rb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at `offsetWidth` for the width of the row but `clientWidth` for the width of a box.

```
var p = z[0].clientWidth;
```

Should be:

```
var p = z[0].offsetWidth;
```

Your variable naming could also be better - and the practice of keeping a live NodeList is frowned upon (better to generate them upfront and keep them in an array) - I've modified your fiddle slightly to be more readable in my opinion https://fiddle.jshell.net/qohLp6rb/1/ (also note HTML is space sensitive).

Comment: Thank's for everything now my code look so professional. :D